# Finding word co-occurrances in R

Tags: r, string, sentiment-analysis, topic-modeling

I have run topic modelling in R. This has returned to me a number of topics and the probability of a word within my dataframe belonging to that topic. For example, topic 7 is 'religion/christianity', and the words below belong to that topic.

"jesus"
"mary"
"christ"
"magdelene"
...

My dataframe is a list of amazon reviews with each cell in the column 'text' being a review. Now, I want to run a sentiment anaylsis of the words that surround these exact words from within my dataframe. However, I'm not sure what is the best way to search for these words. Basically, I want to be able to search for these exact words (using grep(), for example) and also return the 10 words either side of each word, wherever the search word occurs in the reviews. Can anyone help with this? And have I explained my issue clearly enough? Any help is greatly appreciated!

I have tried running a grep() function but don't know how to include the words that surround that word.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to:

1. Split each review into a vector of individual words
2. For each vector, create a numerical vector of the locations of all matching words
3. For each element in *that* vector, create a vector of the locations of all the words in the range to extract.
4. Extract the words and re-stitch them into sentences

Here's a small example using the `stringr` and `purrr` libraries:

```r
library(stringr)  # for dealing with strings
library(purrr)    # for doing the same thing to every element of a list

reviews <- c(
  "I really love this book about Mary and Jesus!",
  "This book is about fruits - including lemon which is my favourite",
  "I learned so much about hinduism, which I thought was really interesting"
)

faith_words <- c("mary", "jesus", "hinduism")

## clean strings - remove punctuation and double spacing
## then make lowercase

reviews <- 
  str_remove_all(reviews, "[:punct:]") |> 
  str_trim() |> 
  str_to_lower()

reviews
#> [1] "i really love this book about mary and jesus"                           
#> [2] "this book is about fruits  including lemon which is my favourite"       
#> [3] "i learned so much about hinduism which i thought was really interesting"


## split strings into lists of words
review_words <- str_split(reviews, pattern = boundary("word"))
review_words[[1]]
#> [1] "i"      "really" "love"   "this"   "book"   "about"  "mary"   "and"   
#> [9] "jesus"

## find the indexes of matching words in each string
matches <- map(review_words, \(x) which(x %in% faith_words))
matches
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 7 9
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> integer(0)
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 6

## Specify words either side
words_either_side <- 2

## I think nested lists will be the easiest way to process this data
matches <- map(matches, as.list)

# Which words define the range we want to include?
word_ranges <- map(matches, map, \(x) (x - words_either_side):(x + words_either_side))
word_ranges[[1]]
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 5 6 7 8 9
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1]  7  8  9 10 11


## map2 lets us use word_ranges to extract words from matching
## elements of review_words

map2(review_words, word_ranges, 
     \(x,y){
       # for each word_range assigned to this review...
       map(y,
           \(z){
             ## select the non-missing words in that range from the review_words
             words <- x[z]
             words <- words[!is.na(words)]
             words <- str_c(words, collapse = " ")
             return(words)
             })
     })
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [1] "book about mary and jesus"
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#> [1] "mary and jesus"
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> list()
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [[3]][[1]]
#> [1] "much about hinduism which i"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>